# Installing IMagick with MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, imagick

Having trouble initializing Imagick with MAMP.

- I've followed [this guide](https://github.com/jdlx/install_Imagick_on_MAMP/wiki/Imagick-for-MAMP-Pro---installation-guide) to a T
- Ran `brew search` and ensured Imagick was installed
- Added `extension=[path]` to php.ini, ensured it's the correct path

Yet when I run `phpinfo()`, I can't find any reference to Imagick, and the Imagick commands don't work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Using PHP 5.4.10, MAMP 2.1.3 (not Pro).

Comment: without seeing some config files, we couldn't begin to help you, only speculate.

Comment: @RichardChristensen I'm fairly new to PHP and don't know which config files are relevant, other than php.ini. php.ini that MAMP was using is rather unweildly, but happy to send you anything you'd like to look at. I also welcome any speculation. Here's php.ini: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q58e96ln0i4rva/php.ini

Comment: This is a seriously bad idea. I strongly suggest using vagrant to install a real linux box rather than struggling with the Mac environment.